# How can I create a priority queue that stores pairs in ascending order?

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I need to create a queue that stores pairs of integers in ascending order by their first value.

Say I have the following queue:

```
0 10
0 10 
1 10 
2 10 
30 10
```

If I try to create a priority queue with these values, it's just going to store the pairs by descending order, starting with 30 all the way to 0.

Is there a way to sort the queue or to just set the order in the declaration?

I'm trying to do:

```
priority_queue<pair<int, int>> queue;

for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    cin>>t>>d;
    queue.push(make_pair(t, d));
}
```

Comment: A priority queue doesn't store values in ascending *or* descending order. It stores them as a heap. What are you trying to accomplish, given that you never actually access the values from the priority queue?

Comment: @Sneftel I'm trying to store pairs in a queue, and the pair with the lowest pair.first() value needs to be at the front of the queue. Should I not be using priority queue then?

Comment: Just realized that storing the highest element at the top is intrinsic to the priority queue. My bad, guess I'm not approaching my problem correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [priority_queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue), the largest element is at the front of the queue.

> Note that the Compare parameter is defined such that it returns true if its first argument comes before its second argument in a weak ordering. But because the priority queue outputs largest elements first, the elements that "come before" are actually output last. That is, the front of the queue contains the "last" element according to the weak ordering imposed by Compare.

You could use `std::greater<pair<int,int>>` as custom comparator or your own comparator as well to have a custom ordering. This will put the smallest element at the front of the queue.

```
priority_queue<pair<int, int>, std::vector<pair<int,int>>, std::greater<pair<int,int>>> q;
```

Comment: Why do we need a vector of pairs as second argument? 
just priority_queue<pair<int, int>, std::greater<pair<int,int>>> q; won't be enough?